# Over stock order quantity error message for grouped product

Tags: magento2

i need help to understand how magento 2 notify users if the ordered quantity of a grouped product is over the stock quantity when adding to cart.
Now, when i try this case, nothing happen. 
Empty cart and no screen messages.
Thank you